# UITableView content is gone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I'm facing a strange behavior of a `UITableView`. I have a View Controller with a `UIView`, let's call it view **A**.

Inside `UIView` **A** I'm calling another view from a `UIViewController`, called view **B**.

HomeViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *B = [[BViewController alloc]init].view;

    [self.A addSubview:B];
}
```

Inside **B**, I have a `UITableView` **C**.

BViewController.m

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    C.delegate = self;
    C.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview:C];
}
```

This `UITableView` is loading correctly but when I just tap on the screen all of the table's content is gone. Just an empty table remains.

Comment: That isn't the right way to do view controller containment.  See the "Adding a Child View Controller to Your Content" section of: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

Comment: I'll read it! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

In your view controller B made property of type A and name it to delegate and set it with instance of A and set that delegate property to your table view' datasource and delegate instead of self. Because in viewdidload of B you are setting delegate and data source as self that means instance of B and your table view is being shown on viewcontrollet A. So A's instant would be the delegate of tableview. So set tableview's delegate and datasource to self in vc A or as i mentioned in above lines.Or you should add vc as childviewcontroller.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately I did not understand what you wrote. Do I need to create a UIView A inside View Controller B and set it as a delegate of an UITableView? Sorry, but I am really confused about what you said. :(

Comment: your viewcontroller (which is presenting tableview) must be a `delegate and datasource` of `tableview`. In your case that is `A` not `B`, because you are showing your tableview on viewcontroller `A`!

Answer (score 0):

Following the official documentation of [View Containers](http://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/%E2%80%A6) my problem was solved.